# htaccess rewrite conflict with wordpress rules and ssl

Tags: htaccess, rewrite-rules, ssl

this one has me buggered- I have the below htaccess rule to redirect ssl to non-ssl pages.  this works fine, except I'd like to exclude certain wordpress requests from this rule- for example, https://mysite.com/info/.  I've tried the following:

```
#rewrite all ssl pages to non-ssl for everything that doesn't have /info/ in the request uri 
RewriteCond %{HTTPS} on
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^/info/
RewriteRule (.*) http://%{HTTP_HOST}%{REQUEST_URI} [R=301,QSA,L]

#wordpress
RewriteBase /
RewriteRule ^index\.php$ - [L]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule . /index.php [L]
```

the result is that https://mysite.com/info/ redirects to http://mysite.com/ instead.  If I disable the wordpress rewrite rules, the preceding rules work fine.  Can anyone suggest the proper way to target pretty urls in a rewrite condition?

Comment: Did you ever figure this out?

Comment: Move the question to stackover community. This need expert .htaccess advice.
Also shared the question on Facebook closed group. Lets see.
Thanks

Comment: @jetlej Is your `https://example.com/info/` an unexisting one?

Comment: @5ervant - Yes it's an existing page

Comment: @Vee - Thanks for the advice. I did this and got an answer! http://stackoverflow.com/questions/31213450/issue-with-htaccess-redirecting-all-pages-to-https-except-one/31214569#31214569

Answer (score 3):

Edit your existing code to exclude the index.php from redirecting like this:

```bsh
RewriteCond %{HTTPS} on
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^/info/
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^/index\.php$
RewriteRule (.*) http://%{HTTP_HOST}%{REQUEST_URI} [R=301,QSA,L]
```

For an explanation, check the answer to this question at Stackoverflow: 
[Issue with .htaccess redirecting all pages to HTTPS except one](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31213450/issue-with-htaccess-redirecting-all-pages-to-https-except-one/31214569#31214569)
.